# How to read data from Google-storage to Cloud-run dynamically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-cloud-run

I have a dash application running on Google-cloud-run This application needs some data in order to work, it reads it from Google-cloud-storage

This data in google-cloud-storage is updated once a week, I am looking for a way to enable reading the new data without the need to re-deploy a new version of the application every week. Otherwise, the application will read the data stored in the memory (old data)

I tried to call a function that downloads the new data (on google-cloud-run's server) but I couldn't load the data to the app because it's already running and reading the loaded data in memory

Comment: What is "dash"?

Comment: Your application should incorporate one of [Google Cloud Storage client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) and read the latest data into memory. There is extensive documentation on the Google site at the link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop to waste you time to update Cloud Run with Cloud Functions. The cloud run containers are immutable (as any container) and the only way to change the data is to build a new container. (solution that you don't want)

---

There, you still have 2 solutions to achieve that:

1. You can read data from Cloud Storage when you start your container.

   - Create a bash script that load the data from Cloud Storage with gsutil, and then start your binary. Put that bash script in the entrypoint of your container
   - Use the Cloud Storage client libraries in your Cloud Run service to load the data
2. Use the 2nd gen runtime execution of Cloud Run and mount the [bucket as a volume on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse).

Comment: Cloud Run is not immutable. The file system is memory based and as is writeable. Sure it is not persistent, but is is very much mutable. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#filesystem. Not only that but cloud functions gen 2 runs on cloud run so even if the answer was correct about immutability, the cloud functions would be immutable too (which they are not, as cloud run is not)

Comment: Ok, file are mutable, the container not (every time a new instance is created, the file start from the beginning, no update done, it's stateless)

Comment: That is persistence. Cloud run services are not persistent. The files and entire service is mutable.